# Cardinallity increasing constructions

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, set-theory

If we start with $\mathbb{Z}$ we can through localization get $\mathbb{Q}$, but that has the same cardinallity as $\mathbb{Z}$, so it doesn't increase cardinality for infinite sets, which is what I am interested in. Completion however goes to $\mathbb{R}$ which has greater cardinality so completion can increase cardinality, not doesn't necciserily. Ultraproduct makes us able to go to ${}^\ast\mathbb{R}$ which still doesn't have greater cardinallity than $\mathbb{R}$. So my question is, is there anyway to algebraicly (combined with analyticly) to go from real numbers to another set that has a greater cardinallity? I am not aware of any and I'd love to know.

Thank you!

Comment: Some relevant discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3uzuno/what_is_a_set_you_have_used_whose_cardinality_is/ A summary of that: people tend to work with things whose cardinality is finite, $\beth_0,\beth_1$ or $\beth_2$. Most other things come up in investigations which have at least some spirit of "set theory for set theory's sake".

Comment: While that is perfectly true I am curious at if there is some algebraic construction method that render algebraic  structures that is strictly larger cardinallity wise. I have not encountered anything beyond $\mathbb{R}$ and it's just a curiosity thing, My gut says it has to exist

Comment: That depends what you mean by "algebraic". You can always make up some weird algebraic object with some weird properties. The question is whether the result is interesting.

Comment: Algebraic I tend to only mean that which is relevant to abstract algebra. So probably something that can fall under the umbrella of universal algebra but not necciserily as something slightly deviant like fields would be acceptable too

Comment: There is always the power set. It's definition is such a simple and basic feature of set theory that you could justify it being part of algebra, or of analysis, or of any branch of mathematics whatsoever. So perhaps you should put more constraints on your question?

Comment: Power set is more set theory and less algebra. You rarely discuss the power set there from my experience.

Comment: An object having a cardinality greater than $\mathfrak{c}$ is more or less well-defined. (OK, in $ZF+\neg C$ cardinals are not totally ordered, and even in $ZFC$, $\mathfrak{c}$ can still be many different alephs. But close enough.) By contrast, being an "algebraic" object or an "analytic" object is not nearly as well-defined. You will need to give a more robust description of what you mean by that if you want an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: (Cont.)  From previous discussions on this subject with mathematicians from a fair variety of subfields, I am pretty confident that any set you can come up with of cardinality higher than $\beth_2$ (note: $|\mathbb{R}|=\beth_1$) will have some flair of "set theory for its own sake" to it. However, stopping at $\beth_2$ there are definitely useful examples out there (all Lebesgue measurable sets, for example).

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to go beyond $2^{\aleph_0}$, you're likely to run into set theory along the way.

Comment: Set theory is everywhere, as lovely as it is, is there something algebraic like the forementioned ones that allows an algebraic structure to go along with?

Comment: Well, the usual construction of larger fields is by taking transcendental extensions obtained by adding a lot of new elements. Or considering $\mathbb F[X]$ for some sufficiently large $X$, then taking a quotient by a maximal ideal.

Comment: How about the [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)?

Comment: Except you dont use the reals to make the surreals